# BufferReader always returns null

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader, filereader

this code drives me crazy it always prints null and i don't why and according to java docs printing null means that the file is empty and it is not in my case .

```
static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("Hosam.txt"));
     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("Hosam.txt"));

     BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
     PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(fw);

     String g = "hosam";
     while ( (g = bf.readLine() ) != null); {
         System.out.println(g));
         pr.print(g);
     }
     bf.close();
     pr.close();
 }
```

Comment: You call readline twice. So if the file has only one line you get null in the second readline statement

Comment: Just a small tip... Formatting your code correctly makes it _way easier_ for other users to diagnose problems.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson thnaks :)

Comment: @Jens  
even i change it to **g** it also prints null .

Comment: @hosamhasan  and you are sure you looking into the right file?

Comment: Maybe you should add two pieces of information: A) the exact printout B) the content of your file [ of course, for testing, your file should actually contain just a few line ]

Comment: @Jens yes , and i also tired with the filepath but gave the same output

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that you're trying to write to the file at the same time as you read it.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson so , what is the problem of reading and writing at the same time ?

Comment: It could cause permission issues. For example, the FileWriter may be failing because the file is currently in use by the FileReader. Alternatively you could be modifying the file's contents as it's being read which could lead to some internal problems.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson
i changed the code and printed the output in another file
`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("Output.txt"));`
and it also printed null.

Comment: remove the semi colon after your while statement. `while ( (g = bf.readLine() ) != null);`  this last semicolon . This is causing you to read the entire file and exit when your g is null. and the following block is just an intance block, won't get executed in the order you are expecting anyway.

Comment: @Jimmy wow , thanks man i did't noticed that extra semi colon;
but , how the compiler did't detect that there was while statement without it its body.

Comment: link of the answer by Jimmy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000409/bufferreader-always-returns-null#comment65353559_39000409

Answer (score 0):

You are calling bf.readLine() **twice**! One time within the loop condition; then within the loop body. Just don't do that!

As it means that you are simply "throwing" away half of your lines!

Comment: even i change it to **g** it also print null